# oracle how can i find the line number for the begin in a procedure / package

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I want to add some code after the begin in every procedure, function and packaged procedure, I have thousands of procedures, packages etc so it would be many weeks of work to do this manually.

I can search all_source but does anyone have any analysis code before I write my own to find the line number for the "begin" as there could be sub routines or anonymous blocks that I need to ignore

eg from user_source

```
package body my_pck is
  procedure proc1 
  is
    v_var varchar2(10);
    procedure sub_proc
    is
    begin
      some code ....
    end;
  begin
< I want to insert code here>
    some code ....

    begin
      anon block ....
    end;
  end;
  procedure proc2 
  is
    v_var varchar2(10);
    procedure sub_proc_something_else
    is
    begin
      some code ....
    end;
    procedure sub_proc_another
    is
    begin
      some code ....
    end;
  begin
< I want to insert code here as well>
    some code ....
  end;
end;
```

So I *think* I need a routine to match up the begin / end to find where to add my code

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need a parser for this task. I created a plsql parser for [Vorax](http://talek.github.io/vorax4/) and you can use it if you like. It's not a full fledged parser, but smart enough to figure out the structure of the plsql code.

Get the vorax4 project from github.

```
cd C:\Projects
git clone https://github.com/talek/vorax4
gem install vorax
```

---

Write a simple ruby code to handle your scenario:

```rb
$LOAD_PATH << 'C:/Projects/vorax4/vorax/ruby/lib/'

require 'vorax.rb'
include Vorax

# You need to get this from your database
package_source =<<EOF

package body my_pck is
  procedure proc1 
  is
    v_var varchar2(10);
    procedure sub_proc
    is
    begin
      some code ....
    end;
  begin
    some code ....

    begin
      anon block ....
    end;
  end;
  procedure proc2 
  is
    v_var varchar2(10);
    procedure sub_proc_something_else
    is
    begin
      some code ....
    end;
    procedure sub_proc_another
    is
    begin
      some code ....
    end;
  begin
    some code ....
  end;
end;

EOF

structure = Parser::PlsqlStructure.new(package_source)

# just print the structure of the package
puts structure.dump

# the code we want to insert
offset = 0
INSERT_CODE = "\n--my code\n"
INSERT_CODE_LEN = INSERT_CODE.length

# loop into the plsql structure
structure.regions.each do |child|

  region = child.content

  # only if it's a procedure/function declared into the body of the package
  if region && child.level == 2 && region.instance_of?(Parser::SubprogRegion)
    pos_to_insert = offset + region.body_start_pos + 'begin'.length

    # insert the code after the BEGIN clause
    package_source.insert(pos_to_insert, INSERT_CODE)

    # adjust the offset
    offset += INSERT_CODE_LEN + 1
  end

end

# print the new version of the package
puts package_source
```

The output is:

```
[Level: 0]
  [Level: 1] PackageBodyRegion: {:start_pos=>2, :end_pos=>467, :name=>"my_pck", :name_pos=>15, :signature_end_pos=>24, :declare_end_pos=>462}
    [Level: 2] SubprogRegion: {:start_pos=>27, :end_pos=>217, :name=>"proc1", :name_pos=>37, :body_start_pos=>145}
      [Level: 3] SubprogRegion: {:start_pos=>77, :end_pos=>141, :name=>"sub_proc", :name_pos=>87, :body_start_pos=>107}
      [Level: 3] AnonymousRegion: {:start_pos=>175, :end_pos=>210}
    [Level: 2] SubprogRegion: {:start_pos=>221, :end_pos=>462, :name=>"proc2", :name_pos=>231, :body_start_pos=>432}
      [Level: 3] SubprogRegion: {:start_pos=>271, :end_pos=>350, :name=>"sub_proc_something_else", :name_pos=>281, :body_start_pos=>316}
      [Level: 3] SubprogRegion: {:start_pos=>356, :end_pos=>428, :name=>"sub_proc_another", :name_pos=>366, :body_start_pos=>394}

package body my_pck is
  procedure proc1
  is
    v_var varchar2(10);
    procedure sub_proc
    is
    begin
      some code ....
    end;
  begin

--my code
    some code ....

    begin
      anon block ....
    end;
  end;
  procedure proc2
  is
    v_var varchar2(10);
    procedure sub_proc_something_else
    is
    begin
      some code ....
    end;
    procedure sub_proc_another
    is
    begin
      some code ....
    end;
  begin

--my code
   some code ....
  end;
end;
```

Other parser options, though I haven't used them, could be:

- ANTLR grammar: https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser
- JAVACC grammar: https://java.net/downloads/javacc/contrib/grammars/PlSql.jj

Answer (score -1):

I think this would be pretty hard (but not impossible) to do. First of all, you need to get the packages from the database. I got some code that can do that:

```
DECLARE
  package_name user_source.name%type;
  last_package_name user_source.name%type;
  package_body CLOB;
BEGIN
  FOR package_cur IN
  ( SELECT * FROM user_source WHERE type = 'PACKAGE BODY' ORDER BY name, line
  )
  LOOP
    package_name        := package_cur.name;
    IF last_package_name = package_name OR last_package_name IS NULL THEN
      package_body      := package_body || package_cur.text;
    ELSE
      --=======================================================
      -- whole package is now in package_body and can be altered
      --=======================================================
      insert into tmp_table values (package_body);

      -- move to next package
      package_body := package_cur.text;
    END IF;
    last_package_name := package_name;
  END LOOP;
  -- processing very last package
  insert into tmp_table values (package_body);
END;
```

Next obstacle is that the code can be outlined in various ways, for all I know the whole package could be written in one line. You'd have to figure out one or another way to first extract all procedures from the package and than bind the appropriate begin keywords.

Comment: When should I vote down?

Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

Use $$PLSQL_LINE. See also $$PLSQL_UNIT.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( $$PLSQL_UNIT || '.' || $$PLSQL_LINE || ': hello ' );
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks but that is reliant on adding that to the code manually ... I want to automate it ... I should add I will be extracting the source to a text file, adding the line of code and then recompiling back into the database .... I'm half way through writing a routine now to do this, I'm just perfecting the logic of having sub routines and not putting my code there!